# Count option is unavailable in calculated column

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I have a query regarding on SharePoint list. In the column heading, there is an option named "Totals" and under this "None or Count" drop-down is available. I have a "Status" column and I picked "Count" from the "Total". It shows the total count at the bottom of how many were planned/completed/canceled a trip under the "Status" column.

I have a calculated column named "Total Planned Days" It is the difference between "Planned Start Date" and "Planned End Date".

I used the below logic. Intentionally I used this formula.

```
=IF(AND([Planned End Date]>0,[Planned Start Date]>0),[Planned End Date]-[Planned Start Date]+1,"")
```

But in the "Total Planned Days" calculated column the "Total" option is missing. The same thing is applied with "Total Actual Days" and there is also the missing "Total" option.

Is there any way to count the total at the bottom?

Comment: What is the returned type of your calculated "Total Planned Days" column, Number or Single line of text?

Comment: Number. Total difference

Comment: Are you using modern (new) experience list in SharePoint online?

Comment: Yes, I am using the modern list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot show "Totals" of SharePoint list calculated columns. This is a limitation of SharePoint calculated columns.

You can find more information and workarounds in below threads:

1. [Total of a calculated column on SharePoint 365 and MS Teams list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/89029/total-of-a-calculated-column-on-sharepoint-365-and)
2. [How to add Total to calculated column in Sharepoint](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-to-add-total-to-calculated-column-in/f9b9f3fa-09f2-4bf6-95a7-0ad1801e06c9)

Comment: Agree with Ganesh Sanap. And per my test, flow is a good workaround in the modern experience.